# Looking for external hard drive storage

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage

Are there reliable companies out there selling external, **USB-powered hard drives** (in enclosures) so I can store my data?
Computers nowadays come with ridiculously small *storage*, and *cloud services* are either expensive, very limited, or incredibly slow (and rely on stable *network* access which I cannot always have when I work).

I don't think I'll ever move past external drive storage for my work, but I have over 5TB of my work files scattered through 5 TB Western Digital drives, and would love to upgrade to larger storage space (I use a cataloging application to know what is on which drive... cumbersome process). I'm not sure how people do it, I assume a lot of digital creator's data grows exponentially with time.

### My requirements are:

-external, USB drive

-comes in a shock-safe enclosure

-SSD or HDD doesn't matter much

-manufactured by a trustworthy company

-no electrical power needed - USB powered

-over 5TB in storage (the larger the better)

I could look into it and make it myself, but I really don't want to - I have limited time and knowledge for computer things and also I don't want to be liable if something goes wrong when I do something as an amateur that a factory knows how to do professionally.

I have found almost similar questions on here, but they seemed outdated so I'm asking again to have 2023 answers.

Comment: Over 5TB powered by USB only and shock safe likely rules out HDD unless there is one that will run on a charging port and is designed for field use. If all your constraints are firm, this is likely to be an expensive drive.

Comment: I did not say anywhere that it had to be a HDD, if there are SSD options out there I have yet to find them - whatever the price...